# Where to post bug/requests on Thunar file manager's bulk rename tool?

Tags: xfce, thunar

I would like to post a feature request concerning Thunar bulk rename tool (namely: an undo option) but I haven't found the place for that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can file a product enhancement request at [Xfce bug tracker | Xfce Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/) .